How to make a navbar dropdown menu like this one?
I am relatively new to webdev stuff and am trying to code drop down menus for a navbar that look like the ones from this website: https://segment.com/
I think the formatting of the dropdown content isn't out my range, but rather whatever the people who made this did to get the dropdown content to appear in the same place no matter which button you press. I have been stuck on this for a while. I can never seem to get dropdown content to not appear right below their corresponding button. I've tried inspecting their code and copying css rules, but it hasn't worked so far.
This is the html I've been working with. It's a base with some of my own additions (I haven't gotten around to the formatting of the dropdown content yet so it's just a list of links I've deleted from this snippet). If it happens to be important, I'm also using bootstrap for this.


.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<div class="navbar-nav navbar-dropdown-container">
  <div class="nav-item headernav-item dropdown">
    <a id="browseDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>Browse</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="browseDropdown">
      <div class="navbar-dropdown-content">
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



Edit: Futher clarification. The base I am using is that of an entire pre-built website, scripts and bootstrap already included. My apologies for not mentioning before. It seems to be running on bootstrap 4 as well as jQuery UI - v1.12.1. I have no problem making functional dropdowns, but I what I want is for the dropdown menus of the navbar to all be the same size and open to the same place like in the website I linked. Right now, they all open below their respective buttons and grow to the right.

Regarding the dropdown content appearance on click: It's a click event which belongs to JavaScript.

I have made you a snippet. The version of bootstrap matters: data-bs-toggle="dropdown" should be used in place of data-toggle="dropdown" in version 5. Please update snippet and tag correctly
